# SQL: Aggregate records within a group taking into account rows order

Tags: sql, postgresql, group-by, apache-spark-sql

I have a table of the following structure

```
| id | a | b |
| 1  | 1 | 1 |
| 2  | 1 | 5 |
| 3  | 2 | 2 |
| 4  | 2 | 3 |
| 5  | 2 | 5 |
| 6  | 1 | 3 |
| 7  | 1 | 7 |
| 8  | 3 | 1 |
| 9  | 2 | 0 |
| 10 | 4 | 8 |
```

and need to calculate the sum in the column "b" within each group in the column "a" but taking into account the order of rows, i.e. at first we should add `1 + 5` for `a == 1` (`id`s 1 and 2), then we will add `2 + 3 + 5` for `a = 2` (`id`s 3, 4, 5) and so on.

Thus, in the result I need to have the table like this

```
| a | sum(b) |
| 1 |   6    |
| 2 |   10   |
| 1 |   10   |
| 3 |   1    |
| 2 |   0    |
| 4 |   8    |
```

Please help to write a SQL query to do this.

Comment: which postgres version?..

Comment: 9.6, but ideally the code should not be attached to a defined PostgreSQL version, because I want to use it in Apache Spark SQL

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
select      a,sum(b)

from       (select   *
                    ,row_number () over (order by id)                as rn
                    ,row_number () over (partition by a order by id) as rnp

            from     t
            ) t

group by    a,rn - rnp    

order by    min(id)  
;
```

P.s.
I'm not counting on ID to be a continuous